# How do I put a custom url in a r-exams question that it will be exported to moodle?

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

The r-exams package offers a possibility to add a url to the question using the macro \url{some link}, however I would like to hide the link and show some text instead, for example: \command{www.r-exams.org}{R/EXAMS}. It's possible?

Comment: use the latex command `\href{URL}{TEXT}`

Comment: Doesn't work because the package hyperref isn't loaded. If I load the package which garanties I have for this works in moodle?

Comment: yeah forget to add that you need to use `header-includes : -\usepackage{hyperref}` in your yaml header.

Comment: R/exams exercises don't have YAML headers so you cannot include it there. Moreover, for `exams2moodle()` the `\href{}{}` command is supported out of the box without loading any additional packages. For further details see my full answer below.

Comment: Did the answer resolve your problem? If not, please refine the question so that we can clarify it. If yes, please accept the question (by clicking the check mark next to it) so that it is flagged as resolved here on StackOverflow.

Comment: exams2moodle always worked but exams2pdf did not because I had not loaded the hyperref package and thus I assumed that both did not work without a template. I was using the pdf as a preview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

In R/LaTeX (Rnw) exercises you can do so with the `\href{...}{...}` command. In R/Markdown (Rmd) exercises you can use the `[...](...)` syntax. See below for `rexams.Rnw` and `rexams.Rmd` respectively.

#### Details

To generate the Moodle XML file for import into Moodle, use

```
exams2moodle("rexams.Rnw")
```

And to preview more quickly what the HTML code looks like use

```
exams2html("rexams.Rnw")
```

In the latter case you can also add the argument `converter = "pandoc-mathjax"` so that you use the same HTML converter that `exams2moodle()` uses by default. The same also works for the `rexams.Rmd` file. Both of the HTML converters (ttm and pandoc) support these syntaxes for the specification of hyperlinks.

Only when converting to PDF the default template will not work but you need to do something like

```
exams2pdf("rexams.Rnw", template = "mytemplate.tex")
```

where `"mytemplate.tex"` needs to be a suitable LaTeX template that includes the `{hyperref}` package. See Section 3 in `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` for further details. The reason the `{hyperref}` is not included in the default template is that (a) `{hyperref}` is quite "invasive" and changes many aspects of the document formatting and (b) the default PDF configuration is intended for printing and not hyperlinking because HTML-based formats are better for the latter.

#### Exercise `rexams.Rnw`

```
\begin{question}
How many times do you see the logo on the
\href{http://www.R-exams.org/}{R/exams web page}?
\end{question}

\exname{R/exams logo}
\extype{num}
\exsolution{2}
```

#### Exercise `rexams.Rmd`

```
Question
========
How many times do you see the logo on the
[R/exams web page](http://www.R-exams.org/)?

Meta-information
================
exname: R/exams logo
extype: num
exsolution: 2
```